# Is the empty string of even length?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions, modular-arithmetic

There is this example of regular expressions:

$$(\Sigma\Sigma)^*= \{w\mid |w|\text{ is even}\}\,.$$

From that I understand the empty string is valid as a string of even length. Is this true?

Comment: Of course zero is even: it is two times zero. By the way: isnt there one $\Sigma$ too much in the expression?

Comment: Ah ok I wasn't even thinking about zero. Nope that's the right number of $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A number is even if it leaves no remainder when divided by two. Zero leaves no remainder when divided by two.

Answer (score 1):

Even number - Even number = even number.
Odd number - odd number = even number.
0 - 0 = 0
Since it cannot change parity it must be even.

Furthermore 0's neighbours are odd, which also implies it is even (as every second number has the same parity).
[Zero parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero)

Comment: What does advice on checking the parity of a number using bitmasks have to do with the question?

Comment: Might as well explain the whole number theory.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that's correct. Empty string is valid as string of even length.

If you consider any language of even length of strings, it will also include an empty string.So, it is true.

Comment: "If you consider any language having even length of strings, it will also include an empty string." That's not true. For example, the language of all strings over $\{0,1\}$ that have even length and contain the string $000$ is a language of even-length strings that doesn't include $\epsilon$ (or any other string of length less than four).

Comment: @DavidRicherby I meant this ' All the languages of even length strings(but don't contain strings other than even length strings ) include empty strings too.' Edit has been done. :)

Comment: But it's not true that all languages of even length strings include the empty string! I just gave you an example showing that that's false.

Comment: @DavidRicherby so can we say that the language of all even length strings including null contains empty string?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.